# HTML5 capture back facing camera

Tags: javascript, html, webcam, capture

I am trying to capture an image from the back facing camera, the code works as expected the phone opens in either front or back, but using the back facing camera I get empty $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] value passed to the php file. If I use the front facing camera a $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] value is supplied to the php file as expected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
   
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"  accept="image/*" capture="environment">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
echo $target_file.'<br>';
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  echo 'check '.$check;
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] .$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please don't add `[Solved]` to your title - please mark the answer that helped you as accepted so there is future canonical references

Answer (score -1):

To answer my own question max_file_size upload needed to be edited in the php.ini file to increase the file size from the default 2m

Comment: The answer was posted by the person who asked the question.
and the question itself doesn't mention anything about the actual issue which definitely makes users not to understand and answer his questions. 

answering own question when the question isn't clear and also not mentioning the actual issue makes it worthles to even post on StackOverflow and not going to be useful for other users